# jQuery - remote validation rule

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#form").submit(function(e){
           if ($(this).valid()){
                $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/My/modules/validate.php",
                });
           }
           return false;
     })});
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                user: {
                    remote: {
                        url: "http://localhost/My/modules/validate.php",
                        async: false,
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
$.validator.setDefaults({
    debug:      true,
    success:    "valid",
});
</script>
```

I want to create remote validation rules. This example correctly reads ajax requests. Though returning true/false both evaluate to validation error.

However, deleting ajax part (jQuery()) results in lack of ajax initialization, the request isn't even handled.

async: false seems to be passive, deleting this results in the same thing.

Anyone could have any slightest idea what could be wrong here?

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                user: {
                    remote: "http://localhost/My/modules/validate.php",
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                // do your ajax form submission here
                return false; // prevent redirect since you did ajax
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Still, it behaves very strangely - $("#form").valid() is always TRUE, and the workflow stops when clicking submit as if it were false.

Comment: This is the whole script...nobody has any idea? Crap, I'm trying to fiure it out for half of this day...

Comment: Why are you calling the same PHP from two places?  Is `validate.php` for validating the one field with `remote` rule, or is `validate.php` for submitting the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an external `submit` handler when using the Validate plugin because it already has all the event handlers built in.

The built-in `submitHandler` is only fired whenever the form is valid and it's where you'd put any `ajax` for form submission.

You are doing `ajax` in two places... with the `remote` rule and with your `submit` handler.

- Use the `remote` rule if your ajax is used for validating a field.
- Use `submitHandler` if your ajax is used for form submission.

This is using only [the `remote` rule, as per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            user: {
                // ajax in remote rule to check this field
                remote:  "http://localhost/My/modules/validate.php"
                }
            }
        }
    });

});

// get rid of all this
//$.validator.setDefaults({
    //debug: true,  // not needed in production
    //success: "valid", // this is already the default.
//});
```

---

The following is only my suggestion **if** you're using ajax for form submission.  Ignore it otherwise.

This is using [the `submitHandler` callback, as per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form").validate({
        // your rules & options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // do your ajax form submission here
            return false; // prevent redirect since you did ajax
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What's "// do your ajax form submission here" by the way? Am I supposed to put something in there?

Comment: @user2115883, I have no idea what you're doing.  `// put your ajax here` is where you'd put your ajax code for a form submission.  Are you using ajax to submit the form?  I have no idea... but that's where it should be placed.

Comment: @user2115883, just pay attention to the first part (about `remote` rule) if that's all you're doing.

Comment: Is it necessary to use both echo 'true' and echo 'false' in some conditional statement in this .php file ?

Comment: @user2115883, [As per `remote` documentation linked above](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options): "The serverside resource is called via `$.ajax` (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a key/value pair, corresponding to the name of the validated element and its value as a GET parameter. The response is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements,... "

Comment: I got the bug...the problem was that I was clicking submit without filling the text field...if I type anything in there, everything work perfectly...I don't know if it's "by design"...

Comment: @user2115883, if you did not make the field `required`, then of course the form will submit when the field is blank... that's by design.  In other words, when fields are not `required`, they are "optional" and will not prohibit submission.